# Run Jupyter notebook from Rust code instead of CLI

Tags: rust, jupyter-notebook, command-line-interface

I have some Rust code that produces multiple CSV files, and it's run from the CLI. What I would like to do is- the soon the CSV files are produced, run Jupyter notebook in web (which uses some python traits) from the code so the user doesn't have to run it manually, is there some way to do this?

So now it goes like:
I run cargo run-> get 1.csv and 2.csv
then I type jupyter notebook and open it in the web

I would like to:
run cargo run
once the function within generates the 1.csv and 2.csv -> JN runs in web without me typing anything more

I found some libraries that open notebooks within rust, I want it to run separately, just skip the part where user manually runs the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to automate it with some kind of shell script.
Which runs the rust program and then starts the notebook.

```bash
cargo run && cd <path to notebookfolder> && jupyter notebook;
```

This should run your program, then navigate to where your notebooks are and then start it.

You can use it as a single line which you reuse in your terminal.
Or save it as `execute.sh` or something like that.
Give it access to be executed by using `chmod +x execute.sh`.

Then you can run it by doing
`./execute.sh`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you correctly, all you want to do is execute `jupyter notebook` from inside your Rust program? If so, you can do so with the [`Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) struct from Rust's standard library. Just add these lines to execute the `jupyter notebook` command from your program:

```
use std::process::Command;

Command::new("jupyter")
    .arg("notebook")
    .spawn() 
    .expect("failed to execute process");
```

Comment: A variation on the commands `jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute mynotebook.ipynb` (see [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-from-the-command-line)) or `jupytext --execute mynotebook.ipynb` (see [here](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html#command-line-conversion)) will work for executing a pre-made jupyter notebook.

Comment: @Wayne thanks for pointing that out. To accommodate your commands, multiple arguments can be passed to the [`args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args) method of `Command`, i.e. `Command::new("jupyter").args(["--execute", "mynotebook.ipynb"])`. or `arg` can be called multiple times, too.

Comment: I'll also add that for parameterizing the notebook itself, there is [Papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill). It may help if the OP hasn't decided how to handle that part yet. (I haven't used it but [Jupyter Scheduler](https://blog.jupyter.org/introducing-jupyter-scheduler-f9e82676c388) also enables this.)